# Griffths buffons needle

Tags: probability, geometry

I've seen a lot of other proofs online about buffons needle, and I understand how they work, but I'm very confused about how Griffiths did this.

I just can't visualize it.

Needle Length L on panels Length L.  What's the probability that if dropped it will cross a line?

He asks to refer to the previous question which goes as

"We consider a broken car speedometer, but we're interested in the x coordinate of the speedometer point (The projection on the horizontal line)"

Now all the questions are easy but Could you explain his answer?

"Suppose the eye end lands a distance y up from the line $ (0<y<L)$ and let x be the projection along the same direction $(-L<x<L)$.  The needle crosses the line above if $(y+x>L)$ or $(x>L-y)$, and it crosses when $(y+x<0)$ or $(x<-y)$.  So the probability of the needle crossing the line is 
(
$$ P(y)=\int_{-l}^{-y} \rho(x)dx + \int_{l-y}^{l} \rho(x)dx=\frac1\pi \{\int_{-l}^{-y} \frac1{\sqrt{l^2-x^2}} dx + \int_{l-y}^{l} \frac1{\sqrt{l^2-x^2}} dx\} $$ And so on until I get $ \frac2\pi $

I understand the math. I don't understand how he got the boundary terms (l-y) or (y) I can picture what if y was half way (l/2)  and x was the full extent (l).  Then I picture a needle  parallel to the boundary, but not crossing any lines??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram below may help. The horizontal black lines are the edges of one panel, so the vertical distance between them is $L$. The circle marks the eye of the needle, at a distance $y$ above the lower edge of the panel. I’ve shown two possible positions of the needle, one in red and one in blue; the point of the red needle is at $\color{red}{P}$, and that of the blue needle is at $\color{blue}{P}$. In each case I’ve projected the needle horizontally onto a vertical line segment; for the blue needle that segment is $\color{blue}{\overline{QP}}$, and for the red it’s the segment from the eye to $\color{red}{Q}$. Ignoring the algebraic sign for a moment, $x$ is the length of the projection; $x$ is positive if the point of the needle is higher than the eye, as with the red needle, and negative if it’s lower, as with the blue needle.

> If we set the origin on a vertical axis at the bottom edge of the panel, the vertical coordinate of the eye is $y$. If $p$ is the vertical coordinate of the point of the needle, then $x=p-y$.

You can see from the picture that if $x>L-y$, so that $x+y>L$, then $P$, the point of the needle, will lie above the upper edge of the panel; this is not the case with the red needle. If, on the other hand, $x+y<0$, as **is** the case with the blue needle, then $P$ will lie below the lower edge of the panel, and the needle will cross an edge; this is equivalent to saying that $x<-y$.

Even if the needle is oriented vertically, $x$ can be no larger than $L$, the length of the needle, or smaller than $-L$ (when the point is directly below the eye). Thus, we know that $x$ can range from $-L$ to $L$. For which of those possible values do we get a crossing (or a touch)? We get one when the point is below the eye and $-L\le x\le-y$, and we get one when the point is above the eye and $L-y\le x\le L$. The first integral in your expression covers the first of those cases, and the second integral covers the second case.

[image]